# How to copy all files in a folder to another folder and change the extension?

Tags: powershell

I have some files in a folder with no extension file. I want to copy all the files to another folder and change their extension to `.txt`.

I tried this code, but it still errors for creating the destination file.

```
$JOB = Copy-Item -Path C:\Users\XX\Documents\Folder1* -Destination "C:\Users\XX\Documents\Folder2"
Rename-Item -Path C:\Users\XX\Documents\Folder2\* -NewName *.TXT
```

Comment: So you want to change the extension of all files to `.txt` - did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I want to change all the files extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Path .\Folder1 -File |
  ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination ".\Folder2\$($_.BaseName).txt" }

# Alternatively without ForEach-Object (see note below)
Get-ChildItem -Path .\Folder1 -File |
  Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination { ".\Folder2\$($_.BaseName).txt" }
```

That should do the job. Keep in mind it will work only for one level, if you want recursive copy of folder structure, you'll have to modify the script slightly.

Basically, what's happening here is you find all the files and then pipe them to `Copy-Item` constructing destination path with `BaseName` property of source file (which doesn't have extension included, in comparison to `Name` property).

---

**NOTE**: as `-Path` accepts pipeline input (see [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-6#parameters)), you don't need to use `ForEach-Object`. However, it might still be useful for visibility (depending on your preferences).

<sup>Credits to [@LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) for noticing the above.</sup>

Comment: As `Copy-Item` accepts piped input there is no need to use a foreach, just the `-Destination` parameter has to be a script block =>  `Get-ChildItem -Path .\Folder1 -File | Copy-Item -Destination {".\Folder2\$($_.BaseName).txt"}`

Comment: @LotPings you're right, I tried it but it wasn't working (forgot about brackets `{ ... }`). Thanks, I'll add to the answer rn